# Parsing an html tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to get number that is stored in a tag like
`var x="<a>1234</a>";` using JavaScript. How can I parse this tag to extract the numbers?

Comment: maybe `x.match(/\d+/)` can help...

Comment: What have you tried? Also, that's not a tag, it's a string.

Comment: In general i am calculating some stuff and saving it with tag <a>. I am doing this several times but i want to add every result after calculation is done. After saving the value with <a> tag i need to get it back to  add value and save it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the HTML and get value from the tag.

There are 2 methods :

1. Using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) :

```js
var x="<a>1234</a>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(x, "text/html");

console.log(doc.querySelector('a').innerHTML)
```

2. Creating a dummy element

```js
var x = "<a>1234</a>";
// create a dummy element and set content
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = x;

console.log(div.querySelector('a').innerHTML)
```

---

Or using regex(not prefered but in simple html you can use) :

```js
var x = "<a>1234</a>";

console.log(x.match(/<a>(.*)<\/a>/)[1])

console.log(x.match(/\d+/)[0])
```

REF : [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x="<a>1234</a>".replace(/\D/g, "");
alert(x);
```

should work

Comment: Thanks for response!

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = "<a>1234</a>";
var tagValue = x.match(/<a>(.*?)<\/a>/i)[1];
console.log(tagValue);
```

**it is by Regular Expression, assume x hold the value of the parsed html string:**

Comment: Please add an explanation

Comment: it is by Regular Expression, assume x hold the value of the parsed html string:

Comment: Add that into the answer